# Save the order in Object while inserting numerical keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm parsing an `XML` and building an object with those values.
I have the parse `parseXmlByTag()` function which parse by specific `TAG` - its works good, so consider it is returning what it should return.

```
 this.mytempect = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {
            var temp = {};
            temp.ID = parseXmlByTag(xml[i], "ID");
            temp.name = parseXmlByTag(xml[i], "name");
            temp.phone = parseXmlByTag(xml[i], "phone");

            if (this.mytempect[temp.ID] == null)
                this.mytempect[temp.ID] = [];
                this.mytempect[temp.ID].push(temp);
        }
```

Before I save each object I check if I need to create for him a new `Key` or to add to existing one, in the end I get something like this:

```
Object {56: Array[1], 70: Array[1], 78: Array[3]}
```

But the first one was with `ID` 78 and the second one was with ID `70`.When I using `.push()` its automatically place it by his `ID` numerical number - if its bigger
than after, else before.

I need to save the order in which I'm getting them so I'll save them in the order I entered them(the order I created the keys) like this:

```
Object {78: Array[1], 70: Array[1], 56: Array[3]}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You'll have to use arrays. Object keys in JavaScript (as in many languages, I guess) are not ordered.

Comment: There is no ordering in an object, so you can't save anything.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in JavaScript are a lot like HashMaps in other languages, if you're familiar with those - in other words, the data is kept in key-value pairs, but no order is specifically retained. So, you cannot rely on the object's member variables staying the same, because they won't.

You'll need to use a data structure that *does* preserve ordering, like an array.